# Why DB constraints are not added during table creation

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between these to ways of table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME(
field1....
field2...

add constraint constraint1;
add constraint constraint2;
)
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME(
    field1....
    field2...
    )

ALTER TABLE TABLENAME add constaint1
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME add constaint2
```

Moreover the first scripts fails on the SQL+ but they pass on sqldeveloper
Thanks!
Pratik

Comment: you're missing a lot of semicolons (;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference seems to be that the first method is a single statement whereas the second one uses three distinct statements. **IF** the statements succeed, the overall result will be the same.

You might want to check your synthax though (especially the use of ";"):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table1 (
  2     field1 NUMBER,
  3     field2 NUMBER,
  4     CONSTRAINT pk_table1 PRIMARY KEY (field1),
  5     CONSTRAINT chk_table1 CHECK (field2 > 0)
  6  );     
Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE table2 (
  2     field1 NUMBER,
  3     field2 NUMBER);     
Table created

SQL> ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_table2 PRIMARY KEY (field1);     
Table altered

SQL> ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_table2 CHECK (field2 > 0);     
Table altered
```